# How to change margin/gap between line numbers and code?

Tags: phpstorm

How do you change the margin/gap between the line numbers and code? E.g I want to remove the massive gap between the two as seen in the screenshot below:

I am using the material theme: https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains

[image]

Comment: `I am using the material theme.` Is that the syntax theme?

Comment: @jAtkin - Yip it is. Looks like it may of been some kind of bug as I have reloaded PHPstorm and that margin has gone away now.

Comment: Have you been using Presentation Mode or maybe Full Screen mode before that? That's typical artifact that sometimes remains after using them. Typical solution in such case: close and re-open project or restart whole IDE.